# Enable SSO on my web application using Azure

Tags: java, azure, spring-mvc, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory

I have a web based Java application made using Spring Framework. I have a spring security file that authenticates users. I need to enable SSO on my application using Azure Active Directory so that I can integrate it with myapps.microsoft.com. Can someone provide me any pointers or direction.

Thanks.

Comment: Can we assume you have your web app running as well in Azure? Btw authenticating with AD you can you LDAP protocol. What exactly do you have a problem with?

Comment: No my web app is not running in azure. It is a simple java web application hosted on a server. I need to integrate it with microsoft apps and enable SSO in it just like other microsoft apps

Comment: Have you checked this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-saas-custom-apps

Comment: then indeed SAML would be the most feasible way https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/

Answer (score 0):

SSO with with protocol? SAML or OAUTH?
In any case you have to register your app in the Active Directory as SSO Application. In this configuration you also define the OAUTH or SAML Options.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-saas-custom-apps